# Just migrated to pressflow and now users can't log in.. any ideas?

Tags: 6, users

I just migrated to Pressflow (newly downloaded) from vanilla Drupal install, and all of a sudden users cannot log in.  The page simply reloads, but there is no authenticated user.

I am getting the following errors when I flush the cache (and I got them after running update.php):

> Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object in
>   drupal_write_record() (line 3488 of
>   /home/traders/public_html/includes/common.inc). Warning: Attempt to
>   assign property of non-object in drupal_write_record() (line 3488 of
>   /home/traders/public_html/includes/common.inc). Warning: Attempt to
>   assign property of non-object in drupal_write_record() (line 3488 of
>   /home/traders/public_html/includes/common.inc). Warning: Attempt to
>   assign property of non-object in drupal_write_record() (line 3488 of
>   /home/traders/public_html/includes/common.inc). Warning: Attempt to
>   assign property of non-object in drupal_write_record() (line 3488 of
>   /home/traders/public_html/includes/common.inc). Warning: Attempt to
>   assign property of non-object in drupal_write_record() (line 3488 of
>   /home/traders/public_html/includes/common.inc). Warning: Attempt to
>   assign property of non-object in drupal_write_record() (line 3488 of
>   /home/traders/public_html/includes/common.inc). Warning: Attempt to
>   assign property of non-object in drupal_write_record() (line 3488 of
>   /home/traders/public_html/includes/common.inc). Warning: Attempt to
>   assign property of non-object in drupal_write_record() (line 3488 of
>   /home/traders/public_html/includes/common.inc). Warning: Attempt to
>   assign property of non-object in drupal_write_record() (line 3488 of
>   /home/traders/public_html/includes/common.inc). Warning: Attempt to
>   assign property of non-object in drupal_write_record() (line 3488 of
>   /home/traders/public_html/includes/common.inc). User warning:
>   Duplicate entry '0' for key 'tmd' query: INSERT
>   INTO blocks () VALUES () in _db_query() (line 147 of
>   /home/traders/public_html/includes/database.mysqli.inc).

Any help would be so so greatly appreciated!  If I can't figure this out in next couple of minutes, I'll roll back to normal Drupal.

Thank you!

**Edit:  My admin account was already logged in after I ran update.php and is working fine.  It seems like a problem creating a new session.

MORE INFO:  When a user logs in, my log says "Session opened for XXXXX." but it's quite clear the account isn't logged in ($user->uid is not set)

Comment: Quick guess: is your db and filesystem writable by the right user? And is there enough diskspace on the webserver?

Comment: Yeah, it is.  When I revert back to the vanilla Drupal install, everything works just fine!  It's strange.  I also tried a newer version of Drupal and also could not log in.  I'm lost!

Comment: Which version of Drupal ?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem right now for just one user in particular. He get access denied when logging in, but log shows him logged in. However, on my CPU I can log in under his account. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: @dave I never did figure this out and ultimate reverted back to vanilla Drupal.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that's going to be of any help for you, but I had kind of similar problem - on staging site, after upgrade from Pressflow 6.16 to 6.26, users were not able to log in anymore - or actually, according to Watchdog, they were logged in, but still being redirected to log in form.

No warning like yours though, although I assume that in your case they we caused by your admin account already logged in.

At this time prod site was still running Pressflow 6.16.

What helped in my case was changing `$cookie_domain` value in `settings.php` file on the staging server, which "unlinked" staging and prod cookies.

Essentially, before both staging and prod sites were using the same `$cookie_domain` (let's say it was `mydomain.org`), and everything started to work fine after changing it to `stage.mydomain.org` on the staging server.

Perhaps the problem is with the different way of handling cookies, and once our Pressflow is updated on prod server too it will again work fine with the same `$cookie_domain`, but this is still to be tested and confirmed.

Comment: Wow, took me a while to see this.  I didn't end up ever figuring out the answer and just reverted back to a vanilla Drupal install.  This seems a plausible solution, so I'll accept it.  Thanks.